# Cómo detener una función?

Tags: javascript

Miren estoy diseñando una web app de radio online. Al abrir la app tengo un botón play/pause que funciona con normalidad.
También tengo una sección que se llama podcast.
El problema es el siguiente: y es que cuando le doy clic para escuchar el podcast, no se detiene el audio que captura la radio sino que se solapan los dos. Es decir, se escuchan los dos.

La verdad es que he borrado todo lo que he intentado porque nada me funcionaba. Les comparto el javascript de la función play/pause

```
var player = document.getElementById('player');

var controlBtn = document.getElementById('play-pause');

function playPause() {
    if (player.paused) {
        player.play();
        //controlBtn.textContent = "Pause";
        controlBtn.className = "pause";
    } else { 
        player.pause();
         //controlBtn.textContent = "Play";
        controlBtn.className = "play";
    }
}

controlBtn.addEventListener("click", playPause);
player.addEventListener("ended", function() {
  controlBtn.className = "play";
});
```

No sé como hacer para detener esta función para que se escuche sólo el podcast

Comment: colocales una clase en comun y solo debes recorrer todos y pausarlos execto el que deses que se quede reproduciendo puedes capturar el que se le dio click con el `event.target`

Comment: Gracias Bryro pero no sé como hacerlo. estoy comenzando en el tema de javascript y he léido tanto que me siento saturado.

Comment: Si mue pudiese guiar con el código te lo agradecería.

Comment: Aquí está el div donde se reproduce el podcast.                                     <!--- Podcast --->
 <div id="pod_cast" class="podcast">
  <div id="sonido" class="pods">
       <iframe src="https://www.ivoox.com/player_es_podcast_796115_zp_1.html?c1=14314a" width="90%" height="400" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" scrolling="no" loading="lazy"></iframe>
   </div>
  </div>
 <!--- end podcast --->